# This python C module I wrote is just returning inf

Tags: python, c, module

So I'm just trying to learn C, this is literally my first day of coding with C so expect accordingly.

I'm trying to make a python module that takes a numpy array, slides a window across it, and for each subwindow it should calculate the standard deviation, and store this in a new numpy array which it returns to python.

For some reason, this returns 'inf' in python, or very large numbers (depending on which random line of code I change). I tried simplifying the calculation to just the mean (so in effect, this is a crude low-pass filter), but I'm still getting these absurd values. I have a feeling that there's something about how I take and return values to python that I'm missing.

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>


float calculateStandardDeviation(float *arr, int startIndex, int windowSize) {
    float mean = 0.0;
    float variance = 0.0;

    // Calculate the mean of the subarray
    for (int i = startIndex; i < startIndex + windowSize; i++) {
        mean += arr[i];
    }
    mean /= windowSize;

    // Calculate the variance
    for (int i = startIndex; i < startIndex + windowSize; i++) {
        variance += pow(arr[i] - mean, 2);
    }
    variance /= windowSize;

    // Calculate the standard deviation
    float standardDeviation = sqrt(variance);
    return standardDeviation;
}

static PyArrayObject *method_stdarray(PyObject * self, PyObject *args){
    PyArrayObject *inputArrayObj;
    int windowSize, stepSize;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "Oii", &inputArrayObj, &windowSize, &stepSize)) {
        return NULL;
    }
    //Make sure it's a numpy array
    if (!PyArray_Check(inputArrayObj)) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "Input array must be numpy array.");
        return NULL;
    }
    // Get dims of array
    int ndim = PyArray_NDIM(inputArrayObj);

    // Make sure its a 1D-array
    if (ndim > 1){PyErr_SetString(PyExc_BaseException, "Input numpy array has too many dimensions."); return NULL;}

    if (PyArray_TYPE(inputArrayObj) != NPY_DOUBLE) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Input array must be of type float64.");
        return NULL;
    }

    //Get the size
    int arraySize = PyArray_Size(inputArrayObj);

    npy_intp size = PyArray_SIZE(inputArrayObj);
    double* inputArray = PyArray_DATA(inputArrayObj);


    if (inputArray == NULL) {
        PyErr_NoMemory();
        return NULL;
    }


    int numWindows = (arraySize - windowSize) / stepSize + 1;
    npy_intp numpyWindows = numWindows;
    //PyObject *resultList = PyList_New(numWindows);

    PyArrayObject* resultArray = (PyArrayObject*)PyArray_EMPTY(1, &numpyWindows, NPY_DOUBLE, 0);

    if (resultArray == NULL) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_MemoryError, "Failed to allocate memory for the result array.");
        return NULL;
    }

    double* resultData = PyArray_DATA(resultArray);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < numWindows; i++) {
        int startIndex = i * stepSize;
        float result = calculateStandardDeviation(inputArray, startIndex, windowSize);
        resultData[i] = result;
    }
    
    Py_INCREF(inputArrayObj);

    return (PyObject*)resultArray;

}


static PyMethodDef meanyMethods[] = {
    {"vararray", method_stdarray, METH_VARARGS, "Takes a list and two integers, returns a new list of variances of subwindows"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};


static struct PyModuleDef meanymodule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "meany",
    "My set of functions for analysing mea data",
    -1,
    meanyMethods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_meany(void) {
    import_array();
    return PyModule_Create(&meanymodule);
}
```

And here's how I call it in python

```
import meany
import random
import numpy as np

fakeList = np.ones(100)
for i in range(0,100):
    fakeList[i] = fakeList[i] + (random.random())
stdList = meany.vararray(fakeList,20,1)

print(stdList)
```

Comment: If you are brand new to C, then starting out with mixed-language programming and a complicated framework such as Numpy seems extremely challenging.

Comment: You haven't included `math.h`, but you are calling `pow` and `sqrt`. And did you link with the math library?

Comment: On the other hand, you should not use `pow()` for small integer exponents.  Especially not for squaring.  Using ordinary multiplication instead is faster and (often) more accurate, and it does not create a dependency on the math library.

Comment: In `method_stdarray()` you extract the input data into an array of `double`.  But you pass (a pointer to) that to `calculateStandardDeviation()`, which expects (a pointer to) an array of `float`.  There may be other issues, but that one is an absolute killer.

Comment: Note too that `double` is C's basic floating-point type.  Do not use `float` in C without knowing exactly why you shouldn't use `double` instead.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thank you! The discrepancy in the function expected input types and what I gave it was one problem for sure, now I'm getting much more reasonable values. Thank you.